# Howto start and detach screen with user environment on startup?

Tags: bash, shell-scripting, gnu-screen

I want to start screen and put a couple of programs running inside on startup.  I've seen many similar posts but none answered my question.
so I put in `rc.local` following 2 lines:

```
  screen -dmS scr bash -c 'ytop; exec bash'
  screen -S scr -X screen 1 bash -c 'nvtop; exec bash'
```

which works fine, but when I enter this screen, once logged in to the server, and want to create new screen, it doesn't have environment variables in it.  How can I start it in the way that would have all root's envars? 
new window looks like this:

```
sh-5.1#
```

`$PATH` in window is 
`/usr/bin:/bin`

Yet in the `rc.local` created windows `$PATH` (`/usr/bin:/bin`) is the same, but the prompt is normal, so it looks that it reads `/etc/profile`

 Window initialized by rc.local has normal prompt:

```
[root@mysrv ~]#
```

PATH is also a bit more than fresh window, but not same as if I start screen manually from the terminal as root

```
echo $PATH
usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

When I start screen by myself it's normal prompt.

```
[root@mysrv ~]#
```

and

```
echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Interestingly if I exit `ytop` it shows me proper prompt.  Only when creating new screen somehow looses this envars.
I tried also running:

```
su - root -c `screen -dmS scr bash -c 'ytop; exec bash'`
```

but I get the same result.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.  It's very simple.
I had to edit file `/etc/screenrc` and add following line

```
defshell -/bin/bash
```

And than it works normally when starting screen in detached mode (`screen -dmS scr bash -c 'ytop; exec bash'`), and also when later entering this screen and creating new window, bash environment will be present.

bellow solution also didn't work.

> So to start screen with normal shell and variables you have to do it >with `init`, so :

> su - root -c `screen -dmS scr bash -c 'ytop; exec init'`

> So this will have normal environment like if you manually start screen >and detach it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem here is the session-handling of bash. Bash - like any other shell interpreter - detects if it is started in the backgroud, or if it is attached to a terminal ( Interactive / Non-interactive mode ). Background is found [here](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files).
My guess is, that your problems are solved by providing the `-l` switch to the first bash command:

```
screen -dmS scr bash --login -c 'ytop; exec bash'
```

The `--login` switch makes bash read all startup files, like `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` - which should contain the environmental variables you are missing.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, but it didn't work when ran from `rc.local`.  Maybe I would need to specify user, but didn't find it manual how to.  But interesting really is i I quit `ytop` in screen one it shows me normal bash prompt (so obviously it read `/etc/profile`, `~/ .bash_profile`  files.  When I enter and attache screen and create new screen then it suddenly looses all those variables.

Comment: Hmm... okay, that is weird. The --login option doesn't have user credentials; it changes only the way bash is run. (use ```su - <login>``` to start a process as a different user). If the problem is only with the second screen command, why don't you create a second session like this: ```screen -dmS scr2 bash -c 'nvtop; exec bash'```

Comment: I tried putting into `rc.local`  su - root -c `screen -dmS scr bash -c 'ytop; exec bash'`, but same result, maybe are the quotes.  What I do normally is always have several screens within one screen session open on each server, so I'd like to create a few starting screens automatically every time server is rebooted.  Then I login go to screen and add new screens.  I want them all under one session, so it's easier to manage.

Comment: the ```rc.local``` is executed as root, so ```su - root``` does not change anything.

Comment: I checked `$PATH` and it is `/usr/bin:/bin`, whereas if I start screen manually is `/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`, so also any programs that I start without this path would start.  still interesting is windows that I start within rc.local have good PS (prompt) but as mentioned starting new one doesn't carry over `$PS` variable from `/etc/profile`